# NSPredicate IN query from array elements

Tags: swift, nspredicate

Apologies for a quirky title. I have an array of Ints and I would like to define an NSPredicate that will filter out items with connectionType equals to a value contained in the array.

So basically something like:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "connectionType IN { all items in array }
```

I've found some Objective C examples that I think deals with this, but I just got into iOS development and have only worked with Swift, so some help here would be greatly appreciated :)

I tried doing this:

```
 fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "connectionType IN \(myIntArray)"
```

However, this returns an NSInvalidArgumentException. I feel I'm close though.

```
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "connectionType IN [28, 28]"
```

If I do the following:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "connectionType IN %@", myArray)
```

I get this error instead:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (connectionType IN {28, 28})'
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You would construct a predicate like this:

```
NSPredicate(format:"connectionType IN %@", yourIntArray)
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and it seems like it's almost working. However, I get the following error:NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "connectionType IN [28, 28]"

Comment: Nevermind, it worked once I realized I had a one-to-many relationship and adjusted accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: @ardevd your comment saved my day, was making the same mistake, had to array into an array