# coreData returning only one result

Tags: core-data, swift4, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

Having this weird issue, No matter what predicate I apply its only returning one result, and if I don't add any predicate its returns all the rows of the table, what I want is only return the rows with matching progIds

I have the list of programIds and based on that I want to search in TvInfo table.

```
.......
......
progId = [Int64(3211),Int64(16844)] // hardcored ids from tvInfo table 
let tvInfoRequest: NSFetchRequest<TvInfo> = TvInfo.fetchRequest()
        tvInfoRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "progId == %i", argumentArray: progId)
        tvInfoRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true
        tvInfoRequest.resultType = .managedObjectResultType
        var tvShows = [TvInfo]()

        coreDataStack.managedObjectContext.performAndWait({
            do{
                let tvInfoResult = try self.coreDataStack.managedObjectContext.fetch(tvInfoRequest)
                tvShows = tvInfoResult
            } catch {
                fatalError("Error fetching channels displayShow")
            }
        })
```

I thought maybe some issue with progId (type mismatch Int64), so I tried fetching using the tvShow name (with exact showNames from tvInfo table still getting only one result, (first name passed in the array)

```
tvInfoRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "progName MATCHES %@", argumentArray: ["Supercar Superbuild","Kanahiya Bhaiya Live"])
```

weird thing is I used the same logic to fetch progIds from channels Table and its working fine(getting progId with exact matches) and its working for other tables also like channel Id fetching from channel tables

```
// fetching progIds from channel table 
let tvScheduleRequest: NSFetchRequest<TvSchedule> = TvSchedule.fetchRequest()
        tvScheduleRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "chId == %i", argumentArray: channelIds)
        tvScheduleRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true
        var progId = [Int64]()

        coreDataStack.managedObjectContext.performAndWait({
            do{
                let tvScheduleResult = try self.coreDataStack.managedObjectContext.fetch(tvScheduleRequest)
                if tvScheduleResult.count > 0 {
                    for array in tvScheduleResult {
                        progId.append(array.progId)
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                fatalError("Error fetching channels to display show")
            }
        })
```

PS:

1. Its returning 1 row so it's not an issue of context, wrong key,
   thread
2. there are data in table as if I don't apply any predicate its
   returning 100+ rows
3. I am using argumentArray for predicate, not single args CVarArg.

Thanks for help

Comment: I think you have failed to understand something: You do `someProperty == something`, but with something being an Array containing various values while you want `someProperty == OneOfTheItemsOnThatArray`.  You want `IN`: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html or on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35188118/nspredicate-in-query-from-array-elements?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

In predicate try using %@ instead of %i.

tvInfoRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "progId == %i", argumentArray: progId).

One more thing check the variable that you are passing to predicate progId.

Comment: try this also once:
NSPredicate(format:"connectionType IN %@", yourIntArray)